# Отношение между элементами в XSD схеме

Tags: xml, xsd

Возник вопрос по поводу xsd , ситуация такая :
Есть тип страницы (рекламный, страница новостей, портал, зеркало).
и есть параметры :
наличие электронного ящика (только для порталов, зеркал и страниц новостей), наличие новостей (только для страниц новостей), наличие архивов для выкачивания (только для зеркал) 
Как задать привязку этих параметров к конкретному типу ? , XML файл должен выглядеть примерно так :

```
<Type>Рекламный</Type>
    <Chars>
        <E-box>....</E-box>
        <News>...</News>
        <RAR>...</RAR>
        <Voting>...</Voting>
        <Pay>....</Pay>
    </Chars>
```

и таких блоков должно быть несколько , в зависимости от типа , такие то Chars.

Comment: Если память не подводит, то в XSD нельзя прописать зависимость вложенных элементов от значения элемента. Вам XSD для валидации нужен или еще для чего?

Comment: Да для валидации.

Comment: ок, вы можете менять структуру XML или она уже зафиксирована и изменению не подлежит? Если можете, то есть простой вариант с надежной схемой.

Comment: XmlSchema **запрещает** определять элементы с одним и тем же именем, но разных типов. А у вас именно эта ситуация: имя одно и то же: `Type`, - а типы в нём разные: реклама, новости...